# No proper documentation on how to migrate the existing DB in SQLDelight

Tags: database-migration, sqldelight

In some of the stack overflow answers say
1.create new table and drop old tables. how to do that?
2.what is the use of sqm file and when we need to use?
3.what's is the use of deriveSchemaFromMigrations flag while declaring the sqllight db in build.gradle